# Prove $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

In our definition,

$$C_0(R^n) = \{ f\in C(\mathbb R^n):\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0 \}.$$

I need to prove that $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$ is a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$. I can prove it indeed is a subspace, but I can’t see why it is closed. I think the pointwise limit of continuous functions may no be continuous, and so I think it is not closed. What’s wrong in my thought?

I only learned the real analysis and some basic measure theory , having not learned the functional analysis. So a proof without knowledge of functional analysis will be best.

Appreciate a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm is the uniform convergence. And if a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to a function $f$, then $f$ is also continuous.

Now, suppose that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of elements of $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$ which converges uniformly to $f$; you need to prove that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. There is a natural $N$ such that $\|f-f_N\|_\infty<\frac\varepsilon2$. And, since $f_N\in\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$, if $|x|$ is large enough, then $\bigl|f_N(x)\bigr|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Therefore, $|x|\gg0\implies\bigl|f(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$

Comment: I understand it now! I understood the notion of convergence wrong just now. Thank you so much José :)

Comment: @SamWong If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot it, sorry. I have marked it now.